# Is a CPU Frequency / CPU Voltage table possible?

Tags: cpu, overclocking

Is it possible to create a **reliable** table for a CPU for hitting the right voltage when overclocking it? Like this:

*Name: Sample CPU 5 2980j*
-----------------------------
|**Frequency** | **Voltage**|
-----------------------------
| 3,2GHz-----| 1,100V--|
| 3,3GHz-----| 1,150V--|
| 3,4GHz-----| 1,200V--|
| 3,5GHz-----| 1,275V--|
.... and so on

or will every build of the same CPU require a slightly different voltage on the same frequency?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Yes there are going to be difference because there a very fine difference between components. On "lower" levels there's probably not much of an impact but the higher overclock the more noticeable it's going to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and No.

Yes, you can make a table that will always work, but then you have to keep margins very high, and as such you won't overclock much. Most BIOSes nowadays have overclocking profiles with these margins already set.

The no comes from the fact that the better hardware you have, the better you can overclock. Not every CPU is the same and even if the type and model is exactly the same, something in its production process can be slightly different giving slightly different results when overclocking it.

In addition, the cooler largely affects how well the CPU can be overclocked. And if you overclock with instable settings it is possible you damage the CPU, which is why overclocking should always be done in small steps.

With this last statement in mind, I would say no.